# Does $z^2 \bar{z}$ derivative exists at $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

In Spiegel Complex variables book and in Wolfram Alpha it says the function $z^2 \bar{z}$ derivative does not exist anywhere in the complex plane.

But at $z_0=0$

$\frac{z^2 \bar{z}}{z}= x^2+y^2$ then the limit when $z \rightarrow 0$ would be $0$. So the derivative exists.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with what you've done. $z\lvert z\rvert^2$ is complex-differentiable at $0$: in fact, as you've pointed out, $$\lim_{z\to 0}\left\lvert\frac{z\lvert z\rvert^2-0\cdot\lvert 0\rvert^2-0\cdot z }{z}\right\rvert=\lim_{z\to 0}\lvert z\rvert^2=0$$

Comment: Cool! Do you now if there is a reason why https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Derivate+z%5E2+conjugate%5Bz%5D says it is nowhere differentiable at the complex plane?

Comment: You need to ask Wolfram.  (After you consult the documentation for the command.)

Comment: I don't know. For some reason, the command you have given does not evaluate the Wirtinger derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=\frac12\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-\frac i2\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$. I don't know what that does in mathematica language.

Comment: Possibly WA messed up the nomenclature.  Certain it is the function is nowhere _analytic_, since it could be analytic only within a _region_ where the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold, and here those equations hold only at a point $z=0$.  That's what WA should have said.